# Replicate an iterative process with cross apply in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is very basic, it has the Order ID and the time the order is at.

| Order ID | Start Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8:00 |
| 2 | 9:30 |
| 3 | 12:00 |
| 4 | 13:00 |
| 5 | 14:00 |

I need to pay employees 2 hours every time there is an order, however if multiple orders are placed within the same 2 hour window they still only get paid for 2 hour shift. If an order comes in outside of the 2 hour window a new 2 hour shift should be created, and any orders within that 2 hour window will be inside that shift.

| Order ID | Start Time | Shift Start | End Start | Shift # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8:00 | 8:00 | 10:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 9:30 | 8:00 | 10:00 | 1 |
| 3 | 12:00 | 12:00 | 14:00 | 2 |
| 4 | 13:00 | 12:00 | 14:00 | 2 |
| 5 | 14:30 | 14:30 | 16:30 | 3 |

I tried using cross apply and got close, but I'm missing a piece I think to the logic. Maybe the only way to do this is to loop the data but I'm trying to avoid this method for now.

Any help would be appreciated

I tried using cross apply like mentioned above, but theres no way for me to know that order 5 for example shouldn't be grouped with a 2 hour window with order 4... It really needs to go top to bottom, create the shifts, then know if the next record is within that shift.

Comment: What version of SQL server are you using? Run the command `SELECT @@version` and post the first line of the results back here. If SQL Server 2022, the `DATE_BUCKET()` function is what you need. You can can map all order date/time values into two-hour windows with `DATE_BUCKET(hour, 2, [start_date])`. From there you can use group-by or distinct to combine orders with the same bucket.

Comment: (No column name)
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU9) (KB5030731) - 16.0.4085.2 (X64) 
 Sep 27 2023 12:05:43 
 Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2022 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 20348: ) (Hypervisor)

Any help with the query would be appreciated of course :)

Comment: Can you include your query? It sounds like `date_bucket` would be an option for you.

Comment: Show us your attempt

Comment: Why did #5 moved from 14:00 to 14:30?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others suggested for SQL Server 2022, DATE_BUCKET works a treat **but it can also easily be done prior to 2022. Both methods are included in the code below.**

Details in the comments in the code.

**This creates the test table. It is not a part of the solution:**

```
--===================================================================
--      Create and populate the test table as a Temp Table
--      This is NOT a part of the solution.
--      You should always post your example data as "Readily
--      Consumable" data to help others help you better and faster.
--===================================================================
--===== If it exists, drop the test table to make reruns easier.
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable;
GO
--===== Create the test table.
 CREATE TABLE #TestTable
        (
         OrderID    INT     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        ,StartTime  TIME(0) NOT NULL
        )
;
--===== Populate the test table with the given test data.
 INSERT INTO #TestTable WITH (TABLOCK)
        (OrderID, StartTime)
 VALUES  (1,'8:00')
        ,(2,'9:30')
        ,(3,'12:00')
        ,(4,'13:00')
        ,(5,'14:00') --<---<<< This was incorrect in the example output
;
```

**This is the 2022 solution that uses the new DATE_BUCKET function:**

```
--===================================================================
--      Solution for SQL Server 2022 with desired format.
--      Note that its normally not a good idea to format the output
--      in SQL Server but that's what was requested.
--      p.s. I don't use FORMAT() because it's horrible for
--      performance.
--===================================================================
 SELECT  OrderID
        ,StartTime  = CONVERT(CHAR(5),StartTime,108)
        ,ShiftStart = CONVERT(CHAR(5),db.DBTime,108)
        ,EndStart   = CONVERT(CHAR(5),DATEADD(hh,2,db.DBTime),108)
        ,Shift#     = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY db.DBTime)
   FROM #TestTable --<---<<< LOOK!!! Change this to suit!!!
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATE_BUCKET(hh,2,StartTime)))db(DBTime)
  ORDER BY OrderID
;
```

**This is the solution for prior to 2022 but will also work in 2022. Not too much difference in the code:**

```
--===== The old way before 2022. Not much difference, though.
 SELECT  OrderID
        ,StartTime  = CONVERT(CHAR(5),StartTime,108)
        ,ShiftStart = CONVERT(CHAR(5),db.DBTime,108)
        ,EndStart   = CONVERT(CHAR(5),DATEADD(hh,2,db.DBTime),108)
        ,Shift#     = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY db.DBTime)
   FROM #TestTable tt
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(hh,DATEDIFF(hh,0,tt.StartTime)/2*2,0))))db(DBTime)
  ORDER BY OrderID
;
```

Results either way:

[image]